# Why is `お一人様の際は、こちらのテーブルをお使いいただけます` wrong?

Tags: grammar, keigo

In 新完全{しんかんぜん}マスター文法{ぶんぽう}N2 there is an exercise to choose the correct phrase to make the full sentence correct.

> (...)際{さい}は、こちらのテーブルをお使{つか}いいただけます。
>   a) お食事{しょくじ}の
>   b) ご飯{はん}を食{た}べる
>   c) お一人様{ひとりさま}の

I understand why a) is a correct answer and why b) is incorrect.
There was even a question about it before, [link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/why-%E3%81%8A%E9%A3%9F%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AF-instead-of-%E3%81%94%E9%A3%AF%E3%82%92%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AF).

I don't understand why c) is incorrect.

My guess is that `お一人様の` is incorrect because it does not stand for an action like `搭乗{とうじょう}` or `外出{がいしゅつ}` stands.
In case I would want to use `お一人様の` anyway in the sentence, I guess I would have to rephrase it to be like this:

> お一人様**なら**、こちらのテーブルをお使いいただけます。

Comment: 「お一人様の場合は」 is probably better.

Comment: 「お一人様でお越しの際は」 also sounds fine.